# Button troubleshooting in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

By pressing the button, the sale is over and the highest price is announced as the winner.
Here, the button performs the function of the button defined at the beginning of the template file.

(It doesn't do what I explained. It does the work of another button)

(Information about the previous button:A form is created using form.py and sent to the html file with the name of the form in the page_product function.Using this form, the user can add or remove the product to the saved list by pressing the button.I cannot send because of the increase in the number of codes)

views.py:

```
def page_product(request, productid):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=productid)
    off = Bid_info.objects.get(product=product)
    
    bid_max = Bid_info.objects.filter(product_id=productid).latest('bid_price')
    if request.user == off.seller:
        close_button = True
        off.bid_price = bid_max
        Bid_info.checkclose = True
        messages.success(request, f"The offer was closed at {bid_max} $")
    else:
        close_button = False
    context = {
        'product' : product,
        'form': form,
        'off' : off,
        'close_button' : close_button, 
        'bid_max' : bid_max      
    }
    return render(request, 'auctions/page_product.html', context)


def bid(request, bidid):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=bidid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        bid_price = Decimal(request.POST.get("bid_price", False))
        other_off = Bid_info.objects.filter(product=product).order_by("-bid_price").first()
       
        if Bid_info.checkclose == True:
            messages.warning(request, "it sells.")
 
        else:
            Bid_ = Bid_info(product=product, seller=request.user, bid_price=bid_price)
            Bid_.save()
             
    return redirect('page_product', bidid)
```

page_product.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="rectangle-button">
        {% if product.active_bool %}
           <div style="background-color: red;"> remove</div>
        {% else %}
            <div style="background-color: green;">add</div>
        {% endif %}
    </button>
</form>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if close_button %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button> 
    {% else %}
        <p> {{off.seller}} is seller!</p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: @Pycm It doesn't do what I explained. It does the work of another button.

Comment: your form doesn't have "action" url, where to post data. Like ```<form action="/action_page" method="post">```

Comment: ``` It does the work of another button```  Which button? show us the code..

Comment: @Pycm A form is created using form.py and sent to the html file with the name of the form in the page_product function.

Using this form, the user can add or remove the product to the saved list by pressing the button.

 I cannot send because of the increase in the number of codes

Comment: Sounds like problem is in your html template. And you don't post the code. How are we are we going to answer this without the code? Post your code. Remove unnecessary repeating parts to reduce the length of the code.

Comment: @Pycm The template file is complete and I can't send more code. The site gives an error.

Comment: You should at least post the error messages. Are you afraid some people with steal your code?! If someone can solve it, they can code that their own. They don't want to copy anybody.

Comment: @Pycm Dear friend, I get an error, the amount of your codes is too much. and does not post the question. Ok? It hasn't happened to you yet? Besides, didn't you read the question? The button does the work of the save button, which means there is no error.
 And I really don't understand how you thought like that? You have an interesting mentality.And I got answers to all my questions

Comment: Actually you think so... Here "(It doesn't do what I explained. It does the work of another button)" you say button do the work of other button. So problem is in these buttons. Not django. It's html. Maybe check your form ```action attributes ``` they should be different.

Comment: > I am sorry, If I was mean to you. But did you actually solve the problem?

Comment: @Pycm There is no problem. It was a friendly disagreement. Yes, except for this case, I solved the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware Below code is 5% pseudo code. That's because I can't see your models.py, urls.py.

Your urls.py should look like this.

```py
#add
    path('bid/add/<int:product_id>',views.Bid_add, name="Bid_add"),

#remove
    path('bid/remove/<int:bidid>',views.Bid_remove, name="Bid_remove"),

#close
    path('bid/close/<int:bidid>',views.Bid_close, name="Bid_close"),
```

Your views.py should look like this.

```py
def Bid_add(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    if request. Method == 'POST':
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        bid_price = Decimal(request.POST.get("bid_price", False))
        other_off = Bid_info.objects.filter(product=product).order_by("-bid_price").first()
       
        if Bid_info.checkclose == True:
            messages.warning(request, "it sells.")
 
        else:
            Bid_ = Bid_info(product=product, seller=request.user, bid_price=bid_price)
            Bid_.save()
             
    return redirect('page_product', product_id)







def Bid_remove(request, bidid):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=bidid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        Bid_ = Bid_info(product=product, seller=request.user)
        Bid_.remove()
             
    return redirect('page_product', bidid)






def Bid_close(request, productid):

# CLOSE THE BID
    return render(request, 'auctions/page_product.html', context)




def page_product(request, productid):

    return render(request, 'auctions/page_product.html', context)
```

Your forms should look like this.

```html
<form method="post" action="{% if product.active_bool %}bid/remove/{{ bid.id }}{% else %}bid/add/{{ product.id }}{% endif %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="rectangle-button">
        {% if product.active_bool %}
           <div style="background-color: red;">remove</div>
        {% else %}
            <div style="background-color: green;">add</div>
        {% endif %}
    </button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="bid/close/{{ off.id }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if close_button %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button> 
    {% else %}
        <p> {{off.seller}} is seller!</p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: thanks.  fixed. What should I do if I  want to remove the submit price box?

Comment: And the fact that all the products are sold means that it is impossible to offer a price at all.

Comment: OMG, I got something right for your questions. .

Comment: Show the code about `What should I do if I want to remove the submit price box? `. Where is the code? I can't see / find?

Comment: if user.is_authenticated:
            bid_price = Decimal(request.POST.get("bid_price", False))
            other_off = Bid_info.objects.filter(product=product).order_by("-bid_price").first()
           
            if Bid_info.checkclose == True:
                messages.warning(request, "it sells.")

            else:
                Bid_ = Bid_info(product=product, seller=request.user, bid_price=bid_price)

Comment: It is located in another function and is redirected to page_product.

Comment: What is the submit price box? Is the one user put the bid price?

Answer (score 0):

Without defining different action urls with multiple forms inside the same page(template) , all the forms get posted to same url, which is page url form is placed.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="rectangle-button">
        {% if product.active_bool %}
           <div style="background-color: red;"> remove</div>
        {% else %}
            <div style="background-color: green;">add</div>
        {% endif %}
    </button>
</form>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if close_button %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button> 
    {% else %}
        <p> {{off.seller}} is seller!</p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

In your two forms above, define different action urls.
Like below.

```
<form method="post" action="form_1_process">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="rectangle-button">
        {% if product.active_bool %}
           <div style="background-color: red;"> remove</div>
        {% else %}
            <div style="background-color: green;">add</div>
        {% endif %}
    </button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="form_2_process">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if close_button %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button> 
    {% else %}
        <p> {{off.seller}} is seller!</p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

These `action="form_1_process">` 
Makes form submit url as below.
Page_url+"/"+"form_1_process"

Means, form get posted to this url.

Comment: I don't understand. Both forms are in the same function, how can I write a different path??? By giving ID to the forms, will it be ok???

Comment: Ok. Ok. I get your problem finally.

Comment: So your bid Remove and Cancel buttons don't work. But bid Add button works. Right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: I will post more complete answer after sometime. It's bad practice to process 3 methods (add, remove, cancel) in same url and view function.